# Angular 7 configure x-frame-options in localhost IIS Express

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, w3c

- Angular Version - 7.2
- Environment - localhost
- IDE - Visual Studio Code
- Browser - Chrome
- Localhost Web Server - Express

I have project built in angular framework and it is running with **Express web-server in my localhost**. I added the x-frame-options in the web.config but it is not showing up in the webpage response header.

I want to test this change in the app running in localhost. Please suggest, how can i view this property in the response headers.

Web.config code changes :-

```
       <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

[image]