# How to restrict angular app from being loaded in iframe

Tags: angular, angular7, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to restrict angular app from being loaded in `iframe` but not able to do that.

I have `angular` app running independently from `API`. API is implemented using `.net core 2.1` and UI client using `angular 7`.

I tried below different options in `api middleware` but none is working in my case:

> #1
>
> ```
>     app.Use(async (context, next) =>
>     {
>         context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'none'; " +
>             "script-src 'self'; " +
>             "style-src 'self'; " +
>             "img-src 'self'");
>         await next();
>     });
> ```
>
> #2
>
> ```
>     app.Use(async (context, next) =>
>     {
>         context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
>         await next();
>     });
> ```

I am getting above added values in `response header` but still able to load application in `iframe` in other application.

Is there anything I am missing here at `angular/API` side?

**Added more information**

We used IIS to host angular app. Also tried below setting in web.config in angular app:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
    </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not serving the headers in the server side of your UI ? What are you using to serve your angular app ? is it nginx ? apache httpd ? Both of them provide the ability to return headers on every requests

**Edit** : As you are using IIS indeed it seems to be

```
<system.webServer>
  ...

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

  ...
</system.webServer>
```

But I don't know more about it

Sources: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options

Comment: I edited my answer as well, and I found a person with the same issue apparently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728673/angular-7-configure-x-frame-options-in-localhost-iis-express

Without answer...

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you have a separated Front end technology than the one used in the back end, you will use a dedicated server for the front end, and another for the backend.

You could use **NGINX** or **NODEJS** to serve your Angular application and use their proxy features to route the frontend call to you API.

And launch your ASP.NET Core application via the executable/visual studio.

By the way, Angular natively provides a seed configured with Webpack to server your application with reverse proxy support.

Example with ANGULAR
https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Example with NGINX :
https://spencerfeng.medium.com/setup-reverse-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-application-with-node-js-62321f0defb5

**Summary**

DEV:

- Configure Angular proxy feature.
- Start your angular app with ng serve
- Start your API with Visual Studio

PROD:

Configure your webserver to act a reverse proxy and serving the angular app.

Host your ASP.NET Core API in IIS or inside a docker container.